# Gradle generating code coverage report with ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR

Tags: android, testing, gradle, jacoco, androidx

How can I generate the code coverage report using gradle and jacoco with `ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR` and keeping the `clearPackageData` to `true`

In the release notes of `Android orchestartor`. It tells Pass `-e coverage true -e coverageFilePath /sdcard/foo/` flags to generate coverage files in the given location [ref](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/archive/test)

I know of this [bug](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123987001) in the Android Test orchestrator, in which the code coverage files are cleared after each test run. How can I specify the location of where to generate the code coverage files (*.ec files generated by Jacoco) using gradle so that it remains out of the app install directory.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @saiedmomen No i was not able to find a solution. could you find something ?